# "Edits were made which cannot be compiled" . zero errors and Enable and edit and continue is checked in vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am able to edit my code in debug mode but then pop up shows the error that

> Edits were made which cannot be compiled. Execution cannot continue until the compile errors are fixed

but error list is empty and i have checked enable edit and continue.

I am using vs2010.

Cleaning and restarting has not solved the problem.

Comment: Try to delete your Bin and compile again

Comment: Same problem here.. have you found anything?

Comment: I got this same issue. And [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782057/edit-and-continue-feature-stopped-working-in-visual-studio-2010/47008998#47008998) how to fix it.

Comment: Happens in VS 2019 v16.9.4 linked to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/without-any-changes-to-source-files-edits-were-mad/705494

Comment: What a shame that the same issue still exists after more then 10 years (vs2010 to vs2022 to forever ;0 ) !

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio worked for me.

Answer (score 41):

This problem can occur when your workspace broke. Just close Visual Studio, delete (or better first just rename) the `.vs` folder and start Visual Studio again.

It can even happen with VS2017.

Comment: Same issue in VS2019

Comment: After deleting the  .vs folder I still see "failed to emit module" after making a code change.

Comment: @CoreyAlix: "failed to emit module" is not the error of this issue. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692729/csc-error-cs7038-failed-to-emit-module can help you?

Comment: Worked with VS2019 when `ENC1002` occured in error list

Comment: Joining in, same issue in VS2022. Some things never change!

Comment: Get same issue on my VS2022. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 17):

In **Visual Studio**

```
Debug --> Options --> Debugging --> General --> uncheck Enable Edit and Continue
```

Comment: This worked for me, although I also had to stop debugging first ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-and-disable-edit-and-continue?view=vs-2019 ). Note that I wasn't interested in Edit-And-Continue in the first place.  I just wanted to stop this error from coming up when I edited code while debugging.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem (VS2017), for me it was enough to menu item *Build* and click *Clean Solution*
Then *Rebuild Solution* and everything worked fine again.

Comment: Deleting ".vs" folder did not work but simply "Clean Solution" was enough (no need to explicitly "Rebuild Solution".

Answer (score 5):

Potentially this is caused by Visual Studio's `Edit & Continue` feature.
A workaround is to disable this feature:

```
Debug --> Options --> Debugging --> General --> uncheck Enable Edit and Continue
```

Solution taken from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/787089/view.html).

Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828481/edits-were-made-which-cannot-be-compiled-when-using-resharper-in-vs2019/58956614#58956614).

Comment: Is there a real solution of the problem?

Comment: Edit and Continue is not a ReSharper feature.

Comment: You are right, it is a Visual Studio feature.
Hardly worth a downvote though, @GaussZ

Comment: Same error (on v16.11.9) just occurred after a VS hang and crash. Restarted PC. Issue persists. There is a warning `"Feature: 'Edit and Continue' is currently unavailable due to an internal error. Show Stack Trace."` which then displays the error: _"Microsoft.ServiceHub.Framework.ServiceActivationFailedException : Activating the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.EditAndContinue64" service failed. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path is denied._ [truncated]

***Disabling*** **Enable Edit and Continue** worked - but can't be a REAL SOLUTION.

Answer (score 4):

I've had this problem with Visual Studio 2008, 2010, and 2013.  I wrote a batch file I keep in the solution folder for each of my projects when this problem crops up.  Expanding on what Vijay said, this cleans out the bin and obj folders.  Sometimes Visual Studio will have the folders locked and I have to close it, but after I clear these out the problem goes away... for a while.  I'm not sure of the underlying cause, I believe the binaries and the code in memory is somehow getting out of sync.  But this allows a quick close, clean, open solution.

```
@echo off
cls
dir bin /s /AD /b > clean.tmp
dir obj /s /AD /b >> clean.tmp
for /F  "tokens=*" %%A in (clean.tmp) do echo rmdir /S /Q "%%A" 
echo This command will remove ALL BIN and OBJ folders in this tree.
echo To run the commands as listed ...
pause
for /F  "tokens=*" %%A in (clean.tmp) do rmdir /S /Q "%%A" 
del clean.tmp
pause
```

Comment: None of the solutions above this one specifically fixed the problem.  After I ran this script, it fixed.  It may also have been a combination of doing all-of-the-above.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Wonder if cleaning the solution works- it deletes everything in Bin and Obj directories but not the directories themselves.

Comment: @SanjaySubramaniam Greetings sir;  At the time I wrote this, cleaning did not resolve the problem.  It's been a few years, but I think it would say clean, but then the files were still there.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem as well in a c# project. It turns out it was because I had recently enabled the "Enable native code debugging" option.

Turning it off restored the functionality.

Comment: Mixed mode debugger doesn't (apparently, because setting to Managed only fixes it) allow Edit and Continue on managed code.

Comment: Could you more clear about the issues. I have tried in many combination but not resolved.

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar what do you mean? I would get the same window as OP and found it was because of the "Enable native code debugging" option in a c# managed code project.

Comment: @Willster419 Thanks for the response, I had also tried the same way (Using vs2019 latest version and .net core) but failed to get the success. 

If I change the code during debugging it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a regression in Visual Studio 2019 16.9 that affects this features. If you are experiencing this issue check https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Edits-were-made-to-the-code-which-canno/1370525#T-ND1386337 in order to know when the fix will be available.
For Enterprise/Professional versions, a downgrade to 16.8 would be advised.
Hope this helps people experiencing this bug (like myself) since this is the first SO post that comes out in searches.

Comment: How can I downgrade safely?

Answer (score 1):

There is another possible culprit:

It may be a problem with one of the projects that are included in the solution.

I had the exact same problem, as did a co-worker of mine, and the culprit was one of the projects in our .sln file; a WinForms application that was also started in connection with several other projects in the same solution file.

The remedy was simple:

Remove the WinForms project from the solution, and start a separate Visual Studio instance, where the WinForm project was separated from the rest. And then it worked. I think there is some file edited when the WinForms application was run, that changed the code, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community updated as to date.

After hours spent trying all the solutions posted in [this thread highlighted by Hao Nguyen in the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782057/edit-and-continue-feature-stopped-working-in-visual-studio-2010/), the only solution that worked was to remove the Workspace and `Map&Get` again.

To remove the Workspace, `File` → `Source control` → `Advanced` → `Workspace` → `Remove`.

Comment: It happens for me in 2019

Comment: @KirstenGreed and did this workaround help you? It would be useful to know for the record.

Comment: Actually my issue is to do with Resharper. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828481/edits-were-made-which-cannot-be-compiled-when-using-resharper-in-vs2019

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a bit late answer but might be it can help out some other technologist. I had faced the same issue in my `VS2019` & `VS2022` and find 2 solutions.

**Solution 01:**

> i. Tools/Debug => Options => Debugging => General --> Enable Edit and Continue **[uncheck it]**

> ii. Rebuild Code

> iii. Tools/Debug => Options => Debugging => General --> Enable Edit and Continue **[check it again]**

**Solution 02:**

> i. Close your **Visual Studio**.

> ii. Delete the .vs hidden-folder (For safe side, rename it instead to delete)

> iii. Reopen your Visual Studio and run the project again.

Hope it'll work!

Answer (score -1):

This type of error message could occur in three categories as I know so far:

1. Visual Studio setting, like you have to set Visual Studio IDE environment properly
2. Source control related
3. Your method of code does have an interop related API that doesn't like  to be edited in the debugging mode

Most people could fix their problem by going through #1.  To make sure if your Studio setting is right, simply run a new and very small solution, and edit it in debugging mode.  If that gives you the same error message, then your problem is with Bill Gates:), go fixing the configurations.  If no error, shift focus to your own code.

Try to edit in debugging mode in a separate method in your solution.  This error could be method dependent if the critical part is not in the global area.  After narrowing down the problem to a method, well, you are close to a good luck.  Commenting out most or all contents in the method, and gradually un-comment the lines.  You will eventually ping down to the point where the problem gets triggered.

In my case, it is the Excel file application that caused the problem. The solution: I created the objects of Excel app, workbook, and worksheet as global variables, and open and defined them in one of my main method.  Somehow, after doing so, Bill Gates doesn't like to me fool around the method any more in debugging mode.  My trick to go around Bill is to write the workbook opening and worksheet definition in a small separate method, and just call that it from the original method.  After that, I can happily edit any part in the big method during debugging run time!  Still, I cannot do that in that small method that just contains the workbook and worksheet handling.  Well, that is Bill's comfortable work place:)  I don't need to.