# VS 2019 Edit while debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on C# winform application.When i'm trying to apply changes while debugging as i used to do at VS2017 it gives me the below confirmation message and when i press edit it give me error "ENC1002 Cannot apply changes -- unexpected error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJq5R.png)

Comment: [MOD] - make sure you add clear and relevant log. if you are using image make sure it's embedded and not direct link

Comment: I've never had that error before today, but now I keep having it. I expect a bug in VS. I would advise to restart VS, possibly the computer. BTW, do you still have the issue?

Comment: I had the same issue today - restarted the machine and it went away.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not reproduce your problem, I will give the following advice.

First, you can close the vs and delete the hidden folder(bin,obj folder).

Second, it may be an issue in vs2019 16.4, you can look at [Compilation errors when stepping over breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219423/compilation-errors-when-stepping-over-breakpoints).

You can update your vs2019 version to the latest version。

Comment: i want to use this feature not to disable it. but when i'm trying to do so it gives me the mentioned error

Comment: I have modified my answer, you can check if my advice is useful.