# Edits were made which cannot be compiled. When using Resharper in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have a multi project solution using .Net Core 2.1
With VS2019 16.3.9 and Resharper 2019.23 Build 192.0.20191016.60459

If I try to run a test in debug, it will run ok once.
On the second run I will get the error

> Edits were made which cannot be compiled. Execution cannot continue
>   until the compile errors are fixed.

I have tried deleting the .vs folder

A similar [question is asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053323/edits-were-made-which-cannot-be-compiled-zero-errors-and-enable-and-edit-and) but I thought it was worth starting a new question as this is related to Resharper.

I get the error in the VS unit test window and in Resharper's test window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Potentially this is caused by Visual Studio's `Edit & Continue` feature.
A workaround is to disable this feature:

```
Debug --> Options --> Debugging --> General --> uncheck Enable Edit and Continue
```

Solution taken from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/787089/view.html).

Comment: Allows changes, but the debugger continues with the old source, one expects to run the source as one sees it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure than your debugging things are like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUXUh.jpg]